# Unexpected cores synchronization in pcntl_fork()

Tags: php, multiprocessing, fork, pcntl

I'm researching multi-core optimization abilities in PHP. My test program forks 4 processes so that each one should run twice as long as previous.
Code is:

```
 $iters =  20000000;

 for ($c = 0; $c < 4; $c++) {

    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid == 0) {

        for ($i=0; $i < $iters * (pow(2,$c)); $i++)
           $x = $i << 2;

        exit(0);
    }
 }
```

Now after looking at CPU cores load graph, i've noticed that 2 cores finishes job almost at the same time:
[image]
Sometimes even 3 cores tries to synchronize and their load falls approximately in the same time.

Question is - Why each one of cores not finishes job after twice as many time previous core needed according to PHP test script ? And why two cores finishes job almost at the same time ?

Machine specifications `(lscpu output)`:

> CPU(s):                4
>
> On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
>
> Thread(s) per core:    2
>
> Core(s) per socket:    2
>
> Socket(s):             1

Can it be that this effect is related that test machine has only 2 real cores, so somehow this effect is related to hyper-threading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had chance to repeat experiment on machine with 4 physical cores. `lscpu` output about machine CPU specification:

> CPU(s):                4
>
> On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
>
> Thread(s) per core:    1
>
> Core(s) per socket:    4
>
> Socket(s):             1

And I've got such CPU load graph when running experiment:
[image]

So it can be seen that in this case there is no cross-core synchronization and each core is loaded with about twice as many work as previous one.
Confirmed that above mentioned effect is related that test machine had 4 virtual cores (2 physical x 2 hyper-threads) and not just 4 physical ones.